# Why Python3.2 can't deepcopy(globals())?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I have run these codes in python 3.2.2 IDLE:

```
from copy import deepcopy
deepcopy(globals())
```

And i get the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\　  　 　\python\copy deepcopy.py", line 27, in <module>
    deepcopy(globals())
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 147, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 236, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 290, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 147, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 236, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 174, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copy.py", line 285, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
  File "D:\Program Files\Python32\lib\copyreg.py", line 88, in __newobj__
    return cls.__new__(cls, *args)
TypeError: object.__new__(NotImplementedType) is not safe, use NotImplementedType.__new__()
```

So I don't know why we can't do deepcopy() to globals()?

Because that the deepcopy() change the globals dict when it exec?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not because `deepcopy` change the globals dict when it executes, but as the exception shows it, during it's process, it encounter the special `NotImplemented` [built-in constant](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/constants.html), an element of type `NotImplementedType` which it can't instantiate and thus copy.